# What is one’s mother-in-law’s mother-in-law called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, kinship-terms

What is one’s mother-in-law’s mother-in-law called?

Comment: English is not particularly rich in kinship terms. I'd call her *Edith*.

Comment: _Mother-in-mother-in-law-in-law._

Comment: @JohnLawler I know redundancy reinforces, but I almost think you have one too many *in* instances infixed in there. Plus one wonders just what sort of fixture *mother-in-law* is: is she an infix or a circumfix? I guess she’s mesoclitic, but be sure never to skimp on that word’s last syllable.

Comment: One must always get one's innings in. The idea of such a kinship term (which can be described in technical terms but has zero usage in practice) is simply amusing.

Comment: Your *mother-in-law-squared* of course!

Comment: Grand-mother-outlaw?

Comment: Kevin Bacon's 2nd degree in-law? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Degrees_of_Kevin_Bacon

Comment: @WS2, I feel there should be some kind of *mother-in-verse-square-law* joke.

Answer (score 5):

*[Grandmother-in-law](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grandmother-in-law)* has been accurately suggested (I linked Merriam-Webster). If you want to be specific about which grandmother-in-law, you could say "my *father-in-law's mother*".

You can add "-in-law" to any term of kinship to denote [affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_%28law%29) as opposed to blood relationship.

Answer (score 4):

There's no single word for this in English.

Your mother-in-law is the mother of your spouse. The mother-in-law of the mother of your spouse is the mother of your spouse's father and so is your spouse's paternal grandmother.

You can call this person your 'grandmother-in-law' or your spouse's grandmother, but it is not widely understood to mean that.

Comment: There is an unexamined assumption here that your spouse's parents have not divorced and separately remarried.

Comment: Thanks for putting it clearly. One’s spouse’s grandmother seems clear enough.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: That's complicating matters. What is usually sought after is the term for the simplest situation and this is already complicated enough. As there isn't a single word for this one, do you think there would be for the more complicated situations?

Comment: No, *complicated* is when your in-laws reign in Thebes. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could call her your [grandmother-in-law](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grandmother-in-law) because, assuming the usual circumstances, she would be your spouse's grandmother.

Comment: But of course she could be your ***step-*** *grandmother-in-law*, if your mother-in-law remarried.

Answer (score 1):

Grandmother-in-law. As far as I know there is no widespread practice that distinguishes how many 'levels' of in-laws separate you from someone.

Comment: True, but in this case, it is only one level. Your spouse's father's mother.

Answer (score 0):

Given my relationship with my mother-in-law, and her relationship with her mother-in-law, I'd have to say a staunch ally in my struggles. The enemy of my enemy is my friend. =)

Comment: Amusing, but probably better suited as a comment rather than an "answer'.

Comment: Insufficient permission. =( I can only comment on my own answers.